# Detecting duplicates in a file generated using the sliding window concept

Tags: java, duplicates

I am working on a project where I have to parse a text file and divide the strings into substrings of a length that the user specifies. Then I need to detect the duplicates in the results.

So the original file would look like this:

```
ORIGIN
    1 gatccaccca tctcggtctc ccaaagtgct aggattgcag gcctgagcca ccgcgcccag
   61 ctgccttgtg cttttaatcc cagcactttc agaggccaag gcaggcgatc agctgaggtc
  121 aggagttcaa gaccagcctg gccaacatgg tgaaacccca tctctaatac aaatacaaaa
  181 aaaaaacaaa aaacgttagc caggaatgag gcccggtgct tgtaatccta aggaaggaga
  241 ccaccactcc tcctgctgcc cttcccttcc ccacaccgct tccttagttt ataaaacagg
  301 gaaaaaggga gaaagcaaaa agcttaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa cagaagtaag ataaatagct
```

I loop over the file and generate a line of the strings then use `line.toCharArray()` to slide over the resulting line and divide according to the user specification.  So if the substrings are of length 4 the result would look like this:

```
GATC
ATCC
TCCA
CCAC
CACC
ACCC
CCCA
CCAT
CATC
ATCT
TCTC
CTCG
TCGG
CGGT
GGTC
GTCT
TCTC
CTCC
TCCC
CCCA
CCAA
```

Here is my code for splitting:

```
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(toSplit);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length - (k - 1); i++) {
            String s = "";
            for(int j = i; j < i + k; j++) {
                s += chars[j];
            }
            if (!s.contains("N")) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: given that the input file can be huge, how can I detect duplicates in the results?

Comment: Is it important that the result be in the same order as the input?

Comment: note that you can encode A,C,G,T as 0,1,2,3 in 2 bits, all possible combinations for substrings of length 4 give you 4^4 == 256 possibilities: you can remember the last position of a string in an array of size 256 and output collisions as a sequence of blocks put in the array replacing a valid position

Comment: @BeyelerStudios he gave length 4 as just an example. The substrings could be any length.

Comment: @RedRoboHood I suspect a small character count - so I pointed out a possible approach specially for genetic data or other strings with small character sets (that's why it's not an answer)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios A DNA string with 17 characters (4 letters = 2 bits per character) takes 34 bits, which cannot fit into a single `int`. So you could use neither a plain array nor a HashSet for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to check duplicates a Set would be a good choice to hold and test data. Please tell in which context You want to detect the duplicates: words, lines or "output chars".

Comment: I need to detect  words (substrings ) duplicates

Comment: Is the only way for doing that, by rewriting the results after splitting into a third file and reading it line by line again ?

I saw the solution at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996041/deleting-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-using-java)

but now I can't split the file and detect duplicates using the same file ...

Comment: I would not rewrite the results into another file. You can create a new Set at startup with  `Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>();`,  on extracting a word use  
`String word = "extracted";  
if (wordSet.contains(word)) {  
    // ... duplicate  
} else {  
    wordSet.add(word);  
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> substringMap = new HashMap<>();
int index = 0;
Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
```

For each `substring` you pull out of the file, add it to `substringMap` only if it's not a duplicate (or if it is a duplicate, add it to `duplicates`):

```
if (substringMap.putIfAbsent(substring, index) == null) {
  ++index;
} else {
  duplicates.add(substring);
}
```

You can then pull out all the substrings with ease:

```
String[] substringArray = new String[substringMap.size()];
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> substringEntry : substringMap.entrySet()) {
  substringArray[substringEntry.getValue()] = substringEntry.getKey();
}
```

And voila! An array of output in the original order with no duplicates, plus a set of all the substrings that were duplicates, with very nice performance.

Comment: it's a good answer in principle, but for large amounts of data (as OP pointed out) this is inefficient (compared to hashing). also I think OP wants to *detect duplicates* not eliminate them (as your last snippet suggests).

Comment: @BeyelerStudios As I said in my answer, you could use a HashSet if you want, and override `hashCode` in the Subsequence class. I chose not to do so in my example because that doesn't work for larger substring sizes. To detect duplicates but not eliminate them, you could add extra code to the comparator that makes a note every time it finds a duplicate.

Comment: you're wrong: Set (and by extension HashSet) guarantees that unique elements `a`, `b` where `!a.equals(b)` can both be added - that doesn't depend on their `hashCode()`, `HashSet` will indeed contain all unique strings you insert in it! Edit: [Demo](http://ideone.com/QyRKyF)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Ah, so HashSet uses a combination of `hashCode` and `equals`? I must have forgotten that (but now I don't see how that couldn't be true). I'll update my answer with that in mind.

Comment: I greatly simplified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) or a table of hashes to detect possible duplicates and then make a second pass over the file to check if those "duplicate candidates" are true duplicates or not.

Example with hash tables:

```
// First we make a list of candidates so we count the times a hash is seen
int hashSpace = 65536;
int[] substringHashes = new int[hashSpace];
for (String s: tokens) {
  substringHashes[s.hashCode % hashSpace]++; // inc
}

// Then we look for words that have a hash that seems to be repeated and actually see if they are repeated. We use a set but only of candidates so we save a lot of memory
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (String s: tokens) {
  if (substringHashes[s.hashCode % hashSpace] > 1) {
    boolean repeated = !set.add(s);
    if (repeated) {
      // TODO whatever
    }
  }
}
```